# Docker system time sync with the windows docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, timezone, windows-container

I am running an asp.net core application on a windows docker. Simply, application authenticates with Google API to upload & download files.

The application works fine on localhost with IIS Express.
But on windows docker container it's populating an **error**:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with a skew to account for clock differences between systems."
```

I took a look at "docker system info" time was ok. But I went into the container to check the time it was 10 hours later than the "docker system time".

I stuck with this error, please help.

Comment: I would assume issue is not time skew but time zone and seems to be affecting only Hyper-V containers and is fixed in Windows 1709 (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32518)

Comment: Ever found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @msr no, i have not. I simply changed windows container to linux container. This error is only appears in windows docker containers.

Comment: This looks like the [current issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37283) for the windows container time sync problem.  More history in this [closed issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1288).  I have not been able to find a working windows container image, despite reports in the issues.